# What is the use of platform drivers?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to know what are platform drivers? What is the use of platform drivers?
I want to study about platform drivers, What is the starting point for study?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platform drivers follow the standard driver model convention, where
discovery/enumeration is handled outside the drivers, and drivers
provide `probe()` and `remove()` methods.  They support power management
and shutdown notifications using the standard conventions.

[Source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt)

Comment: +1, Good to see that someone understands this question :-|.